# Using an OrderedDict within a dictionary declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have the following fairly complex data structure:

```
temp_dict = {
    'a': {
        'aardvark': (6,True),
        'apple': (3,True)
    },
    'b':{
        'banana': (2,False),
        'bobble': (8,True)
    }
}
print(temp_dict['a'])
```

It's a dictionary(temp_dict) that contains another dictionary layer (a,b), that contains another dictionary (aardvark, apple) that contain tuples.

But this outputs:
`{'apple': (3, True), 'aardvark': (6, True)}`

I *don't mind the order of a,b*; but I need the `aardvark, apple` layer to be an orderedDict - they have to remember the order they were inserted in (which will never be sorted). So I've tried:

```
temp_dict = {
    'a': OrderedDict{
        'aardvark': (6,True),
        'apple': (3,True)
    },
    'b':OrderedDict{
        'banana': (2,False),
        'bobble': (8,True)
    }
}
```

But that just gives me invalid Syntax.
How do I do this? None of the examples I've found has shown declaration of a OrderedDict within another data structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
temp_dict = {
    'a': OrderedDict([
        ('aardvark', (6,True)),
        ('apple', (3,True)),
    ]),
    'b':OrderedDict([
        ('banana', (2,False)),
        ('bobble', (8,True)),
    ]),
}
```

Comment: I don't pretend to understand the difference between the two answers (though @sweeneyrod has updated his) - but who am I to question the experts? :-) Thanks both!

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan, the only differences are that I'm using lists whilst sweeneyrod is using tuples (tuples are immutable, thus more effective in this case), and that I'm appending a comma to every item of the list (include the last one) which is usefull if you are changing the order in the list, or adding new elements by copying existing ones and changing values.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
temp_dict = {
    'a': OrderedDict((
        ('aardvark', (6,True)),
        ('apple', (3,True))
    )),
    'b':OrderedDict((
        ('banana', (2,False)),
        ('bobble', (8,True))
    ))
}
```

(but also consider switching to using classes. I find that dictionaries with more than 1 layer of nesting are usually the wrong approach to a problem.)

Initializing an `OrderedDict` with a dictionary guarantees insertion order being kept *after* the initialization.

```
>>> d = OrderedDict({1: 2, 3: 4})
>>> d[5] = 6
```

`d` must now either be `OrderedDict([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])` or `OrderedDict([(3, 4), (1, 2), (5, 6)])`.

On the other hand:

```
>>> d = OrderedDict([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
>>> d[5] = 6
```

`d` can only now be `OrderedDict([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])`.

Comment: Ahh, I was missing some non-obvious regular brackets. Yup, that works fine. Thank you! (and ridiculously quickly too! ;-) )

Comment: This example gives wrong result for when entries `aardvark` and `apple` have changed order (similarly `banana` and `bobble`) because you are using an unordered dict to fill an ordered one, which of course loses it's order.

Comment: @kroolik Oh yes, I forgot how how ordered dictionaries worked. Your answer is correct.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan I may have answered quickly, but actually incorrectly. A dictionary isn't necessarily ordered, so an `OrderedDict` initialized with one won't be either.

Comment: @kroolik - Just updated my question to clarify, but I don't need sorting. They just need to remember the insertion order. Which of these answers do that?

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan Both versions (my previous and krooliks) would remember insertion order **after** the initialization. However, my previous version did't take into account the ordering of the dictionary initizalising the OrderedDict.